# how to Reverse a RowFilter Work in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

i have RowFilter that is working with no problem on my code !

```java
sorter = new TableRowSorter < > (((model)));

List < RowFilter < Object, Object >> rfs = new ArrayList < > (2);

if (jRadioButton2.isSelected() == false) {
    String regex1 = "(?i)^" + CompanyNameFilter.getSelectedItem() + "$";
    rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex1, 9));
}

if (jRadioButton3.isSelected() == false) {

    if (!CompanyFilterText.getText().equals("") && CompanyFilterText.getText() != null && !CompanyFilterText.getText().equals("تبحث عن شيء ؟")) {
        String regex3 = "(?i)" + CompanyFilterText.getText();
        rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex3));
    }
}

if (!searchFilter.getText().equals("") && searchFilter.getText() != null && !searchFilter.getText().equals("تبحث عن شيء ؟")) {
    String regex2 = "(?i)" + searchFilter.getText();
    rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex2));
}

RowFilter < Object, Object > af = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);
sorter.setRowFilter(af);
jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

As in my code i use a lot of cases to filter a table by user selected.

however i need to do one think that to Reverse a `RowFilter` Work so what i need As Example :

simply the filter instead of searching for (AB) And showing the result in the jTable i want it to Hide the result and showing the rest that is not = (AB) !

So i need to Reverse This Working Code :

```java
String regex2 = "(?i)" + searchFilter.getText();
rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in [`RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#notFilter(javax.swing.RowFilter))

> Returns a `RowFilter` that includes entries if the supplied filter does *not* include the entry.

Comment: I ended up With Error : `method notFilter in class RowFilter<M#2,I#2> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: RowFilter<M#1,I#1>
  found:    String,int `

Comment: this is a cast problem... the error is thrown with `rfs.add(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex2)));` ? Not sure about where is the error...

Comment: `String regexHider = "-";
rfs.add(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regexHider, 0)));`       I think it works, but instead of hiding the results, it eliminates the rest of the filters !

Comment: Working With This Code :            `String regexHider = "(?i)^" + "-" + "$";

            rfs.add(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regexHider, 0)));` Thank You